# JavaScript library for automatic pagination with swipe support

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a mobile project wherein the 2000-odd words of text content is broken into screen-sized pages, with swiping used to navigate the pagination.

There really are two separate tasks here:

1. Breaking an element of arbitrary length into responsive, screen-sized chunks.
2. Paginating those chunks using swipe gestures.

I've been trying to get [jQuery Mobile's pagecontainer widget](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecontainer/) to do what I want, but the default JQM styles are messing up my Foundation project and it seems like `pagecontainer` will only get me about 40% of the way there. I've also considered using something like [SwipeJS](http://swipejs.com/), but I'd still need to figure out how to divide the content into responsive chunks.

Any suggestions? Thanks!