# JavaScript library to display products with pagination, search, sort/filter options

Tags: open-source, library, javascript

I want to show retrieved product list with  **pagination**, **search** and **sort/filter** options for my e-commerce project like below image:

[image]

I have searched over internet & got many free JavaScript libraries.But the following was the closer match with my objective requirements:
[jplist](https://jplist.com/datasourcesexamples/php-mysql-demo)

But I don't know if there are other good ones suitable for the given purpose. So please suggest me the good one.

Comment: Not exactly duplicates, but have a look at these two questions: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/2086/6957 and https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/18291/6957.

Answer (score 0):

A Grid control like Syncfusion [EJ2 Grid](https://ej2.syncfusion.com/16.2.41/demos/#/material/grid/gridoverview.html) can be used to display tables with paging, searching, sorting and filtering.

[Paging demo](https://ej2.syncfusion.com/16.2.41/demos/#/material/grid/defaultpaging.html)

[image: Syncfusion EJ2 Grid Paging]

[Sorting demo](https://ej2.syncfusion.com/16.2.41/demos/#/material/grid/sorting.html)

[image: Syncfusion EJ2 Grid Sorting]

[Search demo](https://ej2.syncfusion.com/16.2.41/demos/#/material/grid/search.html)

[image: Syncfusion EJ2 Grid Search]

[Filtering demo](https://ej2.syncfusion.com/16.2.41/demos/#/material/grid/filtermenu.html)

[image: Syncfusion EJ2 Grid Filtering]

The library is open source, but not free (see details below for a free option though)
[Github](https://github.com/syncfusion/ej2)

The entire product is available for free through the [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense?refer=srecs39882) program if you qualify (less than 1 million USD in revenue).

Note: I work for Syncfusion.